# How unfold operation works in pytorch with dilation and stride?

Tags: python, pytorch

In my case I am applying this unfold operation on a tensor of A as given below:

```
A.shape=torch.Size([16, 309,128])
A = A.unsqueeze(1) # that's I guess for making it 4 dim for unfold operation
A_out= F.unfold(A, (7, 128), stride=(1,128),dilation=(3,1))
A_out.shape=torch.Size([16, 896,291])
```

I am not getting this 291. If the dilation factor is not there, it would be [16,896,303] right?
But if dialtion=3 then it's 291 how? Also here stride is not mentioned so deafualt is 1 but what if it is also mentioned like 4. Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also here stride is not mentioned so default is 1 but what if it is
> also mentioned like 4.

Your code already has `stride=(1,128)`. If stride is only set to `4` it will be used like `(4,4)` in this case. This can be easily verified with formula below.

> If the dilation factor is not there, it would be [16,896,303] right?

Yes. Example below.

> But if dialtion=3 then it's 291 how?

Following the formula given in pytorch docs it comes to `291`. After doing `A.unsqueeze(1)` the shape becomes, `[16, 1, 309, 128]`. Here, `N=16`, `C=1`,  `H=309`, `W=128.`

[image]

The output dimension is, `(N, C * product(kernel_size), L)`. With `kernel_size=(7,128)` So this becomes, `(16, 1 * 7 * 128, L)` = `(16, 896, L)`.

`L` can be calculated using the formula below with multiplication over each dimension.

```
L = d3 * d4
```

Over height dimension `spatial_size[3] = 309`, `padding[3] = 0` default, `dilation[3] = 3`, `kernel_size[3] = 7`, `stride[3] = 1`.

```
d3 = (309 + 2 * 0 - 3 * (7 - 1) - 1) / 1 + 1 
   = 291
```

Over width dimension `spatial_size[4] = 128`, `padding[4] = 0` default, `dilation[4] = 1`, `kernel_size[4] = 128`, `stride[4] = 128`.

```
d4 = (128 + 2 * 0 - 1 * (128 - 1) - 1) / 128 + 1
   = 1
```

So, using above formula `L` becomes `291`.

##### Code

```
import torch
from torch.nn import functional as F

A = torch.randn([16, 309,128])
print(A.shape)
A = A.unsqueeze(1)
print(A.shape)
A_out= F.unfold(A, kernel_size=(7, 128), stride=(1,128),dilation=(3,1))
print(A_out.shape)
```

##### Output

```
torch.Size([16, 309, 128])
torch.Size([16, 1, 309, 128])
torch.Size([16, 896, 291])
```

##### Links

- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Unfold.html
- https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.functional.unfold.html

Comment: Thanks and I must say nice explanation!